# Swift: Difference between initializing superclass with a convenience initializer and a designated initializer

Tags: swift

Let's say I have a class `Dog` declared as below:

```
class Dog {
    let variable1: String
    let variable2: Int

    init(variable1: String, variable2: Int) {
        self.variable1 = variable1
        self.variable2 = variable2
    }
}
```

And `ChowChow` is a subclass of `Dog`, deliberately declared empty as below:

```
class ChowChow: Dog {}
```

So let's assume now I wish to add an initializer to the subclass `ChowChow`.

My question is this: What is/are the difference(s), if any, between having a *convenience* initializer for subclass `ChowChow`:

```
class ChowChow: Dog {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(variable1: "value1", variable2: 2)
    }
}
```

and a *designated* initializer for subclass `ChowChow`?:

```
class ChowChow: Dog {
    init() {
        super.init(variable1: "value1", variable2: 2)
    }
}
```

Using the following test, I could see that the results are the same for either implementation:

```
let chowchow = ChowChow()
print(chowchow.variable1) // Prints "value1"
print(chowchow.variable2) // Prints "2"
```

Thanks in advance for shedding light!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding basic Swift 4.0- specifications the same differences between designated and convenience initializers apply as in any other case.

Points used here:

- Convenience initializers must call other initializer and ultimately call designated initializer
- Designated initializers must and may only call superclass initializers (if any)
- By default subclasses do not inherit designated initializers from superclass. Assuming that you provide default values for any new properties you introduce in a subclass, if your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers. (see [Automatic Initializer Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID222))

In your example:

```
class ChowChow: Dog {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(variable1: "value1", variable2: 2)
    }
}
```

you did not introduce any designated initializers to `ChowChow` subclass thus, all the designated initializers from superclass are inherited (i.e. `init(variable1:variable2)`). Since convenience initializer must ultimately call designated initializer, you call inherited `self.init(variable1: "value1", variable2: 2)` from your convenience initializer, note self there.

In your second example:

```
class ChowChow: Dog {
    init() {
        super.init(variable1: "value1", variable2: 2)
    }
}
```

you introduce designated initializer `init()` to a subclass. By default designated initializers are not inherited in subclasses, unless some conditions are met (like in the first example). So, in this specific case subclass `ChowChow` has only one designated initializer `init()` and nothing else, since designated initializers must call designated initializers from superclass, you call superclass's `super.init(variable1: "value1", variable2: 2)`, note super here.

For details see: [Initializer Inheritance and Overriding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. However, I am still not sure if the question has been answered thoroughly: What is the difference, if any, between initializing a superclass via a convenience initializer and a designated initializer? I may be wrong but your explanation is more of a description of what my code is.

Comment: That really depends on what you're asking, otherwise this answer has all information required. A lot of other differences are implementation detail and may change, so you don't need to take them into account (to investigate see sources).

Comment: Yes, information is there, which I have also studied prior to asking, but the question is not really answered because your answer looks more like a description of what my code is. But thanks anyway. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Then you really should elaborate on your question, specify exactly what are you asking. Because from different points of view and different layers of abstractions there are differences and there are not. I don't understand which part exactly are you asking about. Like which dispatch does either of them use or how classes/methods are represented in memory, or whatever is relevant to you. I.e. your question is too general and needs specification.

Comment: Don't you think that this is exactly what I'm trying to do, ie. find out what the difference(s) is/are? Anyway, at this moment, I think that I have posted my question as elaborate as I can be. Would add to it as I discover anything solid. And your description of my code is not really helpful to me at this point in time, but thanks for your effort anyway.

Comment: Instead of making me write all this up for you I could know upfront that that's not what you're asking for. That's why people add "what have I tried" or "what I already understand" sections to the posts. So now, I just wasted my time. Not going to elaborate but leave this post here, maybe it cat help somebody.